# Ionic 3 Refresher startY

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

Can you tell me how to use `startY` with the [**Ionic refresher**](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/refresher/Refresher/#startY)? I have used like below.But it is not working? It seems `startY` is a `getter` only method no? We cannot set a value for it.Which is Bad :(

My use case:

At this moment where pull to refresh can be triggered from anywhere on the screen. is there an option on Ionic that the gesture used to trigger pull ONLY works when pulling down is done from the very upper part of the screen?

```
<ion-refresher (ionRefresh)="getData($event)" [pullMin]="180" startY="80">
    <ion-refresher-content pullingIcon="arrow-dropdown" pullingText="Pull to refresh" refreshingSpinner="crescent" refreshingText="Refreshing...">
    </ion-refresher-content>
  </ion-refresher>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**New:**

At this moment you **can't**.They'll provide this feature in the future.
[**Set Refresher startY position**](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/12387)

**Old:**

It's the Y position of where user started to pull the refresher in the page. You can get it like this.

```
refreshList(refresher) {
  this.myService.getList().then((data) => {
    console.log(refresher.startY);
    refresher.complete();
  });
}
```

I don't think you can set a value like mensioned in the question.

Comment: Is that `getter` method only? How can I set the value according to my use case? Can't I achieve that use case?

Comment: i think you can choose to do refresh or not by considering the startY vaule. but I can't think of any way that you can disable the ability to pull down.

Comment: Hmm..It is bad.I asked it as a feature:https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/12387

Comment: You mean this kind of code no? `if (refresher.startY > 100) {
      refresher.cancel();
      return;
    }`.The problem is, still, he can pull it from anywhere on the screen no.I need to disable that functionality.